# Full width background video as banner in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**Here is my Code so far...**

```css
.video-box{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.video-box video{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
  <div class="video-box">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="../videos/spark.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
   </div>
```

What i want to do is:

I'm trying to add a background video as a banner,it was supporting in chrome and Firefox,but not in internet Explorer?how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Which IE version do you need to work?

Try to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` to your HTML file in `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your above mentioned code in IE 11 browser and I found that your code is working fine.

Here is the testing result:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>video demo</title>
<style>
.video-box{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.video-box video{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="video-box">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest you to try to run this example in your IE browser to see whether it is working or not.

If you are using any older version of IE than it is recommended to upgrade to IE 11 version.